# Problem with section and footnote numbering, and verbose citation style in report with parts but no chapters

Tags: biblatex, sectioning, footnotes

I’m using the report class (actually KOMA-Script’s scrreport, but I have the exact same behaviour in the standard report class). I am splitting the document into parts because they are relatively self-contained. However, this is causing me some problems, which I think are probably interconnected in various ways.

Although page numbers should be continuous throughout the document, footnote and section numbers should reset in each part.

Section numbering related issues:

1. Section numbers include chapter. As there are no chapters, section numbers are of the form 0.1, 0.2.
2. Section numbers do not reset when I start a new part, so if Part One contained three sections, the first section of Part Two will be number 4 (well, actually 0.4, see above).

Footnote related:

1. Footnote numbering does not reset when I start a new part.
2. **[EDIT]** I just discovered biblatex’s `citereset` option. Using `\usepackage[style=verbose,citereset=part]{biblatex}` solves this fourth issue. **[Original question for reference]**
   I am using the biblatex’s “verbose” style, where references are given in full (in footnotes) the first time, and then in shortened form thereafter. Perhaps because the footnote numbering is not being reset, if a text has been cited in a previous part any further citation in a subsequent part will be the short form. As the parts are supposed to be almost self-contained this isn’t really acceptable. (In the MWE the footnotes in Part Two should be identical to the footnotes in Part One.)

I think this MWE shows the problems very clearly:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @Book{Pettit:Republicanism,
      author = {Philip Pettit},
      title = {Republicanism: A Theory of Freedom and Government},
      shorttitle = {Republicanism},
      publisher = {Oxford University Press},
      year = 1997,
      series = {Oxford Political Theory},
      address = {Oxford and New York}
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\part{The First Part}

\section{Section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation 
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
consequat.\footcite{Pettit:Republicanism}

\subsection{Sub-Section}

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint 
occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia 
deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\footcite{Pettit:Republicanism}

\part{The Second Part}

\section{Section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation 
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
consequat.\footcite{Pettit:Republicanism}

\subsection{Sub-Section}

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint 
occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia 
deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\footcite{Pettit:Republicanism}

\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: As you don't want chapters why not use the `article` class?

Comment: @PeterWilson I did consider that. But in the standard article class and in the KOMA-Script article class \part doesn’t generate a separate title page. But more importantly it only solves the first issue (getting rid of the leading zero in the section numbers). The other three issues are not resolved.

Comment: Question 4 (the second footnote-related question) is completely unrelated to the other questions. I could answer it, but probably not the other questions.

Comment: @moewe please do! If I stop using `\part` and use `\chapter` instead the other three questions are more or less resolved. (I would prefer section numbers to not include the chapter number, but it’s not a big deal.) And then I would need to investigate a way to give chapters their own title page. I thought the way I initially approached this would be the path of least resistance, but maybe not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well despite a lot of searching before posting my question, I couldn’t find an answer. Now, having asked it, I seem to have found the answers anyway.

Remove chapter number from section number:

```
\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}}
```

Reset section numbering and footnote numbering at each part:

```
\makeatletter
  \@addtoreset{section}{part}
  \@addtoreset{footnote}{part}
\makeatother
```

Reset citations for each part:

```
\usepackage[style=verbose,citereset=part]{biblatex}
```

Fixed MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreport}

\usepackage[style=verbose,citereset=part]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @Book{Pettit:Republicanism,
      author = {Philip Pettit},
      title = {Republicanism: A Theory of Freedom and Government},
      shorttitle = {Republicanism},
      publisher = {Oxford University Press},
      year = 1997,
      series = {Oxford Political Theory},
      address = {Oxford and New York}
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\makeatletter
  \@addtoreset{section}{part}
    \@addtoreset{footnote}{part}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\part{The First Part}

\section{Section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.\footcite{Pettit:Republicanism}

\subsection{Sub-Section}

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\footcite{Pettit:Republicanism}

\part{The Second Part}

\section{Section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.\footcite{Pettit:Republicanism}

\subsection{Sub-Section}

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\footcite{Pettit:Republicanism}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun:

```
\documentclass{report}

\let\part=\chapter
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Part}

\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
    @Book{Pettit:Republicanism,
      author = {Philip Pettit},
      title = {Republicanism: A Theory of Freedom and Government},
      shorttitle = {Republicanism},
      publisher = {Oxford University Press},
      year = 1997,
      series = {Oxford Political Theory},
      address = {Oxford and New York}
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\part{The First Part}

\section{Section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation 
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
consequat.\footcite{Pettit:Republicanism}

\subsection{Sub-Section}

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint 
occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia 
deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\footcite{Pettit:Republicanism}

\part{The Second Part}

\section{Section}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation 
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo 
consequat.\footcite{Pettit:Republicanism}

\subsection{Sub-Section}

Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint 
occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia 
deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.\footcite{Pettit:Republicanism}

\end{document}
```